# ajax post to php not actually writing to the mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#save').click(function() {

        var rows = [];

        for (i = 1 ; i < document.getElementById("schedule").rows.length ; i++) {
            var name;
            var tuesday;
            var wednesday;
            var thursday;
            var friday;
            var saturday;
            var sunday;

            name = document.getElementById("schedule").rows[i].cells[0].firstChild.value;
            tuesday = document.getElementById("schedule").rows[i].cells[1].firstChild.value;
            wednesday = document.getElementById("schedule").rows[i].cells[2].firstChild.value;
            thursday = document.getElementById("schedule").rows[i].cells[3].firstChild.value;
            friday = document.getElementById("schedule").rows[i].cells[4].firstChild.value;
            saturday = document.getElementById("schedule").rows[i].cells[5].firstChild.value;
            sunday = document.getElementById("schedule").rows[i].cells[6].firstChild.value;
            monday = document.getElementById("schedule").rows[i].cells[7].firstChild.value;

            rows[i-1] = "name=" + name + "&tuesday=" + tuesday + "&wednesday=" + wednesday + "&thursday=" + thursday + "&friday=" + friday + "&saturday=" + saturday + "&sunday=" + sunday + "&monday=" + monday;
        }

        for (i = 0 ; i < rows.length ; i++) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save-schedule.php",
            data: rows[i],
            success: function () {
                alert("POST successful");
            }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The javascript array is working correctly and showing the correct format and the ajax success function is executing. It shows the alert "POST Successful" but then after checking the mysql table it is empty.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$conn->select_db("little_caesar");

$name=$_POST["name"];
$tuesday=$_POST["tuesday"];
$wednesday=$_POST["wednesday"];
$thursday=$_POST["thursday"];
$friday=$_POST["friday"];
$saturday=$_POST["saturday"];
$sunday=$_POST["sunday"];
$monday=$_POST["monday"];

$conn->query("INSERT INTO schedule (name,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday,monday) VALUES('$name','$tuesday','$wednesday','$thursday','$friday','$saturday','$sunday','$monday')");

$conn->close();
?>
```

this is the save-schedule.php any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Add error checking to your queries.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply ASSUMING your query can never fail. always check for errors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes im getting an "Undefined Index" for all my variables in my php script. So starting with $name and ending with $monday. They are all showing as "Undefined Index"

Comment: Hmmmm, then look at the console and make sure youn sent the data.

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: @JayBlanchard will do. So the variables are returned correctly. It must be the query then? im pretty sure the connection is made to the mysql database.

Comment: Add error checking to the query or look in the error logs to see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Remove '&' symbol from ajax data change instead of , symbol like

```
rows[i-1] = "{name=" + name + ",tuesday=" + tuesday + ",wednesday=" + wednesday + ",thursday=" + thursday + ",friday=" + friday + ",saturday=" + saturday + ",sunday=" + sunday + ",monday=" + monday+"}";
```

Comment: I made this change, but the table is still empty for some reason

Answer (score -1):

Probably error from your MySQL username. Look your PHP code:

```
$username = "";
```

Are you sure your username is blank, because MySQL default username is 'root'.

Comment: This and also the sql server doesnt need a username and password. It's all run on my machine.